# Collections.synchronizedList passed into a constructor

Tags: java, synchronized

I have a brief question.
If i have a list with read/write operations:

```
private List<String> _persistedFilesList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
```

and i have the code block used somewhere

```
new ArrayList<String>(_persistedFilesList);
```

does this block code needs syncronization?
I can see that in the constructor of new ArrayList, in java doc the iterator is mentioned, and all operations involving traversing the list need synch in synchList. but I am not sure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
does this block code needs syncronization?
```

Answer is Yes ( if you need synchronized access to new arraylist you have created).

You have created a new ArrayList using the elements of another list.

JavaDoc

```
 public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)

 Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified collection, in the order they are returned by the  
 collection's iterator.
```

So, regardless whether the collection you passed was synchronized or not, it will be an entirely new list.

Comment: If on the new list i iterate, does it have a link with the synchronized link passed? At the created moment of the new list, if i use synchronized(_persistedFilesList), no read/write operations will be executed on this?

Comment: All operations after creation of your new ArrayList will not have any links with the Collection you used to create the list. So, answer to first question is No. I could not fully understand your second question. Can you please give more info ?

Comment: If i have synchronized(_persistedFileNames){... new ArrayList<String>(_persistedFilesList); }, no read/write operations will be made on _persistedFileNames list at the moment of execution of the code block?